# How do I wait for value to be set in a cypress?

Tags: cypress

I looping through a table and looping through the data of those table in order to compare them. However, I am trying to use break if one of the table data doesn't match to prevent further checking.

I run into a problem here because the break is going to happen inside cy.then, which doesn't work. So now I am trying to find a way to allow the cy.then to set the value then proceed to synchronously check everything else.

Here is what I have tried so far to no avail

```
cy...then((body)=>{
 for (let row = 0; row < body.length; row++) {
   //Body is the table, and we get the table len
   for (let col = 0; col < 4; col++) {
     //Begin looping thru each row's col and compare
     // Here I attempt to create sync code because I want to not continue
     // to loop thru all 4 col if one doesnt match
     let val;
     new Cypress.Promise((resolve)=>{
       cy.get('...').eq(row)...eq(col).then((txt)=>{
           val = txt
           resolve(txt
       })
     })
     //Begin to compare using val and break child loop if needed
 
   }
 }
 })
```

I keep getting val as undefined. I am new to cypress so any pointers would be cool.
Thanks.

What I have tried pt2:
Using async/await in at

```
cy...then(async(body)
```

and awaiting the cypress promise, gets a timeout 4000ms error, increased timeout to 10000ms and still timed out.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: According to your answer, if your code is correct, you can use a [`should`](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/should) instead of `then`, because of possible retriability:

```
cy...should((body)=>{ //over here
 for (let row = 0; row < body.length; row++) {
   //Body is the table, and we get the table len
   for (let col = 0; col < 4; col++) {
     //Begin looping thru each row's col and compare
     // Here I attempt to create sync code because I want to not continue
     // to loop thru all 4 col if one doesnt match
     let val;
     new Cypress.Promise((resolve)=>{
       cy.get('...').eq(row)...eq(col).should((txt)=>{ //or over here
           val = txt
           resolve(txt
       })
     })
     //Begin to compare using val and break child loop if needed
 
   }
 }
 })
```

Comment: Hi, the val variable is placed correctly, as the check is also within the child for loop, but I did as you say anyways. It still did not work, val is undefined. I kind of need the val inside the child for loop as the checking also requires the col index. I also tried adding await and don't work.

Comment: I see, my idea was that the val is needed in the outher loop, that's why it is probably not working. I`ll try to find an idea specifically for the inner one